# Why getOne() blocks deleteById()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I saw that 
`myRepository.deleteById(objectId);`
doesn't work when there is
`myRepository.getOne(objectId)` method used before that.
Can someone explain why getOne() blocks deleteById()?

Comment: Because it's a lazy load that doesn't actually do anything. The entity isn't loaded when you're trying to delete it, and that'll be problematic since you have a reference to the non-loaded-yet-deleted entity.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation. deleteById doesn't need a full entity loaded, it deltes by Id. On the other hand getOne, as you say, @Kayaman, only receives the Id but not the full object. It is not supposed to lock on the db level. So from the information given here I don't see an explanation for the OP either.

Comment: @Ricky did you check if there is a db lock? From the info given here I'm clueless. If Kayamans theory is right, use `findBy` and `remove` should resolve the issue. I doubt the explanation, though.

Comment: Thats right, if i would write "repository.delete(repository.getOne(id));" that won't work. That was the reason of bug at first - used findById() instead of getOne() and deleting works. But when i didn't know that getOne() was causing bug i wrote deleteById(id) in next line to check if this method will work instead of delete(object), and it didnt. But when i commented fragment with getOne(), deleteById(id) started work.

Comment: The default implementation of deleteById already call the findById method.